# Explicitly describe the induced map of coordinate rings.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I think this is an easy problem but I am not sure what it exactly means and how to solve it.

Consider the map $\mathbb{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^3$ given by $t \rightarrow (t, t^2, t^3)$.

Explicitly describe the induced map of coordinate rings.

Would it be $k[x, y, z]/(y - x^2, z - x^3) \rightarrow k[t]$ given by $x \rightarrow t, y \rightarrow t^2, y \rightarrow t^3$?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is your professor speaking. Obviously I can't stop you from posting questions from the problem set here but I cannot for the life of me understand what is the benefit to you to ask here instead of in office hours! Am I really so bad at explaining? Also, this particular question shows that you are not understanding the most basic concepts in the course. The course is going to get a lot harder, and quickly! Wouldn't it be better to take a course at the right level? I welcome the opportunity to talk to you in person. Please make an appointment to come to office hours.

Comment: @KarenSmith: I converted your answer to a comment, since technically it is not an answer to the question. I also needed to edit it slightly (for length), I hope your point still comes across fine after the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the map $\mathbb{A} \to \mathbb{A}^3$.

What you've defined is the map of coordinate rings induced by $\mathbb{A} \to \text{image}(f)$, so it's not quite what you want, but close....

Hint: Without worrying about an explicit description of the map, can you say what its domain and codomain should be?